# Bound on moment generating function gives bound on individual moments?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we know $\mathbf{E} e^{sX} \leq M(s)$. Can we use $M(s)$ to get bounds on individual moments $m_n = \mathbf{E}X^n$?

The other direction holds, since if $m_n \leq M_n$ for all $m=0,1,2,\ldots$ then
$$\mathbf{E} e^{sX} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^n}{n!}\mathbf{E} X^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^n}{n!}m_n \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^n}{n!} M_n = M(s)$$

Comment: For example, if you know $X\geq 0$ (a.s.) then obviously you can bound $\mathbb{E}X^n\leq n!s^{-n}M(s)$.

Comment: Ah interesting, and so the best bound from this method would be given by $\mathbb{E}X^n \leq \inf_{s} n! s^{-n} M(s)$, which you could do with simple calculus like usual. I wonder how tight this can be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $\mathbb{E}\exp(sX)\leq M(s)$ for all $s\in (-\delta,\delta)$.  Then by DCT, $\left\lvert\mathbb{E}\exp(zX)\right\rvert\leq M(\operatorname{Re} z)$ for all $z$ in the strip, and $\mathbb{E}\exp(zX)$ is analytic there, hence we recover
$$
\mathbb{E}X^n=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n}\right\vert_{z=0}\mathbb{E}\exp(zX)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{\mathbb{E}\exp(zX)}{z^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
where $C$ is a small circular contour around $0$ inside the strip.  So the usual M-L estimate gives
$$
\mathbb{E}X^n\leq n!r^{-n}\sup \{M(s):s\in [-r,r]\}
$$
or a sharper bound using $\left\lvert\int_I f\right\rvert\leq\int_I\lvert f\rvert$ instead:
$$
\mathbb{E}X^n\leq n!r^{-n}\int_0^1 M(r\cos 2\pi t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$
where $r<\delta$.